# how to connect two model with a common value present in both the models in my view.py and show the merge data in template file in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model called eligibility check. In that model I have added institute code. I have another model called register, there i have institute name as well as institute code. I want to add a condition so that, all my entries saved in eligibility check get displayed in a table format in my template file along with institute name. I don't have institute name in eligibility check model, so i want to fetch it from register model with a common value institute code , which i have in both models. I tried this, but getting error of The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

View.py

```
def view_eligibility_admin(request):
form1 = Eligibility_Check.objects.all()
code = Eligibility_Check.objects.values('Centre_code')
form2 = Register.objects.get(institute_code=code)
context = {'form1': form1,'form2': form2,}
return render(request, 'view_eligibiity_admin.html', context)
```

Model.py

```
class Register(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institute_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, 
    validators=[MaxLengthValidator(200)])
    institute_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.institute_name)

class Eligibility_Check(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Centre_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    Voter_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True,)
    Present_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, 
    blank=True, choices=yes_no, verbose_name='Add Address') 
    def __str__(self):
    return self.pk
```

I want to have a structure of my template like this[image]

I have institute code in eligibility table and institute name, institute code in register table. so i want to merge both table with the common parameter which is institute code

Comment: Update the question by showing your models. Also, don't share the code snippets as screenshots, it's strongly discouraged. So replace the image you shared with the actual code snippet. See  [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16774936)

Comment: I have added the code of both view.py and model.py.